# how do you get average of top 5 for each records within same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to calculate average for some price as shown below. I am able to do that for each records within that table but how do I do if I want to do this for only first 5 latest dated records? Below query does provide that average but for everything but I am looking for top 5 desc date. This can be solved using row_number() probably but that might be too slow as I have tons of records within that table and row_number processes each row at a time etc. is there any better way doing this? I am trying to do this on SQLServer DB BTW.

```
select a.id, AVG(a.someprice) as avgPrice
 from 
 (select p.id, p.date, calculateSomePrice(p.id, p.date) someprice 
 from table1 p 
 where p.id in (select id from table1)) a
 group by a.id
 ;
```

Let me give you example records that I have on table which can clarify what I am looking for.

```
id    date         prc
1   08/02/2017     1.5
1   08/01/2017     2.5
1   07/31/2017     3.5
1   07/30/2017     1
1   07/29/2017     4
1   07/23/2017     4.5
1   07/20/2017     5
1   07/22/2017     5.5
2   07/29/2017     1.5
2   07/28/2017     2.5
2   07/27/2017     4
2   07/26/2017     4
2   07/23/2017     5.5
2   07/22/2017     3.5
2   07/21/2017     5
2   07/20/2017     0.5
2   07/18/2017     4.5
```

Now when we run above my query, we get average of everything for all the records but what I am looking for is, top 5 average per date for each id. In this case for 1 and 2 both.

below query will give me result for id 1 that I am looking for but I need to do this for all Ids in my table and my table has 481397362 records so doing this in loop doesn't make sense.

```
select a.id, AVG(a.somePrice) 
from (  
      select top 5 p.id, p.date, calculateSomePrice(p.id, p.date) somePrice 
      from table1 p 
      where p.id = 1 
      order by p.date desc ) a 
group by a.id;
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do:  `where p.id in (select id from table1)) a`?  `p` is an alias from `table1`, so the logic is unnecessary.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, I want to calculate average for all IDs inside table1 so it is needed to get me all Ids from that table and than I perform those calculations on price and calculate average on parent query with group by. The only issue here is, I am calculating this for entire result set for that ID where as I want to calculate this average for only top 5 results per date for all the IDs within the same table

Comment: did you mean, top 5 average for each id regardless of date?

so your result for id 1 are
[id    date         prc]
[1   07/22/2017     5.5]
[1   07/20/2017     5]
[1   07/23/2017     4.5]
[1   07/29/2017     4]
[1   07/31/2017     3.5]

is this correct?

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar, so below query will give me correct result for id 1. But I need to do this for entire table and that table has 481397362 records so I can't do this in loop as it will take forever to get me results.

select a.id, AVG(a.somePrice)
from
(  
  select top 5 p.id, p.date, calculateSomePrice(p.id, p.date) somePrice
  from table1 p 
  where p.id = 1
  order by p.date desc
) a
group by a.id;

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar, I have update this on my question again as well so make things more clear. Let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly you can query as below:

```
select a.id, AVG(a.someprice) as avgPrice
 from 
 (  select p.id, p.date, calculateSomePrice(p.id, p.date) someprice,
        RowN = Row_Number() over(partition by p.Id order by p.[date] desc)      
    from table1 p   
 ) a
 Where a.RowN <= 5
 group by a.id
 ;
```

Comment: I think you did understood this correctly but using Row_Number() things gets very slowly. I have 481397362 records in my table and I have ran your query and it is executing since more than 15 mins now. Do you think there is anything faster than this?

Comment: it is still running after 25 mins.

Comment: What is datatype for p.date? What that function calculatesomeprice() function doing? How many records you have in table1?

Comment: I have 481397362 records in table1. calculatesome price() function is doing some calculations which we need to use before we calculate top 5 average of that calculations.

Comment: finally your above query finished and it took 47:37 mins to calculate what I want to calculate. Result looks correct but it is about how we can improve query performance here.

Comment: You need provide sample data and expected output... you might avoid that fn and query correctly which will provide better performance results

Comment: Kandasamy, I need to use that function. I can't ignore using that function. I have already added sample data and expected output on my question earlier. Let me know if anything else is needed?

Comment: In that scenario we need to find out where there is performance hit... I dont think row_number will cause this much performance problem... As you said you must require to use the function... You might require to check other ways to using that function try using cross apply...

Answer (score 0):

You can pick up TOP 5 ids and use them to find out the `average`.

`select a.id, AVG(a.someprice) as avgPrice
 from 
 (select p.id, p.date, calculateSomePrice(p.id, p.date) someprice 
 from table1 p 
 where p.id in (select TOP 5 id from table1 order by update_Date desc)) a
 group by a.id;`

Comment: Nope. That is not my requirement. I want to find this average for all records within table1. So if I select TOP 5 ids than I would not get average for entire result sets.

Answer (score 0):

you can use do it like this:

```
select a.id, AVG(a.someprice) as avgPrice
 from 
 (  select TOP 5 p.id, p.date, calculateSomePrice(p.id, p.date) someprice 
    from table1 p   
    ORDER BY P.DATE DESC
 ) a
 group by a.id
 ;
```

Comment: No. This will not give me top 5 per Id. Your query gives me top 5 from entire table where as I am looking for top 5 records each ID than count average.

Comment: Would you feel like sharing some data and expected result with us  in order to get more accurate answers?

Comment: I just added sample records. Let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query and sample result, we need to tag your top 5 avgPrice in DESC

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT a.id,
       AVG(a.someprice) as avgPrice
  FROM (SELECT p.id,
               p.date, calculateSomePrice(p.id, p.date) someprice 
          FROM table1 p 
         WHERE p.id in (SELECT id
                          FROM table1)
                       ) a
 GROUP BY a.id
)

SELECT id,
       avgPrice
  FROM (SELECT id,
               avgPrice,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY avgPrice DESC) rank
          FROM cte
         GROUP BY id,
                  avgPrice
       ) t

 WHERE rank <=5
```

Comment: No. We need to calculate average of top 5 only. If we calculate average first than it will not be correct value. Please check update that I have done on my question.

Comment: @Fedinand, your recent query does work but it takes 47.58 mins to execute the results. As I have mentioned earlier, my table has 481397362 records and doing ROW_NUMBER() in that case is very costly.

Comment: any other way to make this faster?

Comment: I think the function calculateSomePrice(p.id, p.date) is taking up the time. Could you please check how long the query below runs?

SELECT p.id,
               calculateSomePrice(p.id, p.date) someprice 
  FROM table1

since the query with ROW_NUMBER() has used the result that has already been AVG()'d and GROUPed.

Answer (score 0):

select a.id, avg(a.prc) as avgPrice from
(
SELECT * 
    FROM (
        SELECT id, date, prc, Rank() 
          over (Partition BY id
                ORDER BY date DESC ) AS Rank
        FROM table
        ) rs WHERE Rank <= 5
)
group by a.id